# AngularJS sharing functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controllers have one function that has to be shared between more of them (now I just copied it):

example:

```
   $scope.selectedPartner = { "Name": "", "Id": null };

   $scope.selectPartner = function ($item) { $scope.selectedPartner = $item; };

    $scope.getPartners = function (name) {
        $scope.selectedPartner = { "Name": "", "Id": null };

        return autoComplete.getPartners(name).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.Partners;
        });
    };
```

And a lot of other functions. How can I make something like partnersFunctions() to include these functions to all controllers without copying?

Comment: Why not make a service and then just inject that service into your different controllers?

Comment: Well, I need help about that. I just know how to make a service that returns $http, nothing more. Any resources?

Answer (score 4):

This is where you may find using a service handy.  Check out the documentation at: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/docs/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services